# Python - convert matplotlib plot into a panda dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, matplotlib, reporting-services

Does anyone know how to convert a matplotlib plot into a panda dataframe (either as a PNG or a JPG) without having to save the graphic to a file first. The code here for SQL Server 2017 outputs a varbinary(max) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/sqldev-py3-explore-and-visualize-the-data using pandas and pickle but it is not recognised by SSRS as a valid PNG (or JPG) graphic. The aim to is get Python graphics into SSRS the same way as we do for R graphics via sp_execute_external_script in SQL and a varbinary(max) output.

Comment: If you've got the byte stream for the image from your sql, perhaps you just need to supply the header information for your browser?

Comment: Milo - thanks - but all the information must be in the byte stream panda dataframe/varbinary(max) - that is the way SSRS works when calling a stored procedure for the graphic

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't expect it to be that simple. I don't know much about the conversions between those systems. If you figure it out, post the answer and I'll upvote for learning a little more about them.

Comment: Cool - no it's not simple :-( Over 2000 views on my equivalent LinkedIn post and no answer yet!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The heart of your problem has nothing to do with the `pandas` dataframe per se - the dataframe is only the container of a pickled object here.

Instead of pickling the figure, my guess is you should save the figure to a Python file-like object like [io.StringIO (Python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) or [Stringio (python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pickle

fig_handle = plt.figure()
plt.hist(InputDataSet.tipped)
plt.xlabel("Tipped")
plt.ylabel("Counts")
plt.title("Histogram, Tipped")

output_PNG = io.StringIO()
fig_handle.savefig(output_PNG)

OutputDataSet = output_PNG
```

If the PNG must be contained in a `pandas` dataframe, that can be done too, but I don't know if this data will make much sense...:

```
plot0 = pd.DataFrame(data =[output_PNG], columns =["plot"])
OutputDataSet = plot0
```

Whenever you return `OutputDataSet` now as a `varbinary(max)`, my guess is the contents will be exactly the PNG file.

Curious to hear if this works!

Comment: unfortunately, fig_handle.savefig(output_PNG) gives an error: string argument expected got bytes - I met this error when I was experimenting - now, if we could fix that, that would be perfect - I do not have enough Python knowledge to know the fix - many thanks for trying

Comment: so I tried BytesIO - but still no joy with converting to data frame in the correct format

Comment: over a year later, I revisited the problem - and now have it working with BytesIO and get_value() - thanks vstrien for your initial input which eventually provided the clue

Comment: We are trying to do something similar and running into problems @ArtTennick it will be very helpful if you can post your solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[PythonBinary] as
exec sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)
ax.set(xlabel=''time (s)'', ylabel=''voltage (mV)'', title=''test1'')
ax.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
graphic = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(graphic, format = "png")
df1 = pandas.DataFrame([["test1", graphic.getvalue()]])
ax.set(xlabel=''time (s)'', ylabel=''voltage (mV)'', title=''test2'')
plt.tight_layout()
graphic = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(graphic, format = "png")
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([["test2", graphic.getvalue()]])
OutputDataSet = OutputDataSet.append(df1)
OutputDataSet = OutputDataSet.append(df2)
'
with result sets (( "Graphic" varchar(max), "X" varbinary(max)));
```

Comment: Please add some explaination to your code, so it will be usable for others

Comment: SQL/Python above is my own solution to my original question